# How to access localhost in phone by using localhost in url, not by using ip address?

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a project in which I am trying to add a scanner for which I am using npm **react-qr-scanner** and **react-qr-reader**. But these two npm are only accessed over https or localhost. I want to test this feature on my mobile but I am not able to do it because whenever I try to access it on mobile by providing an IP address, it doesn't work. Even in system also, if I provide an IP address instead of localhost, this functionality doesn't work. Someone please help me here how should I test this feature on my mobile or if someone knows a better way to create a scanner in react JS, please suggest to me.

Comment: Have a look at using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to broadcast localhost from your computer.

Comment: I already tried but no luck.